# JAVASCRIPT- Atributo "onclick" para ocultar elemento?

Tags: javascript

Quiero seleccionar el elemento [0] de una clase y setearle el atributo on click para que al presionarse quede escondido.

Estoy intentando algo como esto:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sf-add-item sf-mt-40 sf-pull-right')[0].attr('onclick','this.hidden=true');
```

Comment: Agrega tu HTML por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El uso de las funciones *in line* aparte de no ser aconsejable, porque hace que el HTML sea dependiente del código Javascript, dificultando el mantenimiento, lleva también a confusiones y complicaciones ante soluciones que serían simples mediante eventos de escucha y selectores.

Para hacer lo que quieres no hay que preocuparse de asignar una función *in line* al elemento, encima de una forma dinámica, modificando el elemento en el DOM. Puedes simplemente implementar eventos de escucha de los elementos de esa clase y ocultar el primer miembro de ella cuando se haga clic en él.

Veamos:

```js
/*
  Alcanzamos únicamente el primer elemento de la clase 
  con un selector específico
*/
var onlyFirst = document.querySelector(".laClase:first-child");

/*
  Registramos para ese elemento un evento que escucha los clicks
  implementando dentro la acción que queremos,
  en este caso ocultarlo
*/
onlyFirst.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.target.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="laClase"><a href="#">Click 1</a></p>
  <p class="laClase">2</p>
  <p class="laClase">3</p>
  <p class="laClase">4</p>
  <p class="laClase">5</p>
  <p class="laClase">6</p>
  <p class="laClase">7</p>
  <p class="laClase">8</p>
</div>
```

Si observas, el código HTML y Javascript son independientes y no se ha modificado nada del DOM para lograr lo que se quiere.

Esto es sólo un ejemplo, si el HTML tiene una estructura más compleja, sólo habría que cambiar el tipo de selector que se usa y nada más. Los selectores tienen un nivel de alcance enorme, con ellos y una buena organización del documento se logran hacer tareas complicadísimas con unas pocas líneas de código.

En algunos contextos en vez de `querySelector` se podría usar `querySelectorAll`, para alcanzar todos los elementos de la clase. Por ejemplo en un contexto en que se deban escuchar los clicks de todos los elementos, si es el primero ocultarlo y si no es el primero cambiar el color del texto. Todo esto se haría dentro de un evento de escuchar basado en  `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso el metodo a utilizar seria setAttribute(),

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sf-add-item sf-mt-40 sf-pull-right')[0].setAttribute('onclick','this.hidden=true');
```

`.attr()` se usa en la libreria jQuery, en este otro caso la llamada seria:

```
$('sf-add-item sf-mt-40 sf-pull-right::first-child').attr('onclick','this.hidden=true');
```